# How to Integrate my Python with Django and HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

Hi I'm extremely new to Django, like yesterday new. I was scouring the web for hours searching for a way to integrate a simple Python project I made to Django in order to keep me on track. I want to use Django as I'm going to be using Django in my classes soon and would like to learn. Is there any way I can do this?

*WANTS:* I want to use Python for my backend & Django framework to link some HTML, CSS, and possible JavaScript to make thing look nice.

**Python Timer Project**

```
import time
import os
from threading import Thread

def userTimeSet():
    while True:
        try:
            hours = int(input("Number of hours? "))
            minutes = int(input("\nNumber of minutes? "))
            if hours > 0 and minutes > 0:
                interval_sec = (hours*3600)+(minutes*60)
                print(f"hours and minutes to seconds checking: {interval_sec}")
            elif hours > 0 and minutes == 0:
                interval_sec = (hours*3600)
                print(f"hours to seconds checking: {interval_sec}")
            elif hours == 0 and minutes > 0:
                interval_sec = (minutes*60)
                print(f"minutes to seconds checking: {interval_sec}")
            else: print("invalid.")

            futureTime = timeConfirmation(hours, minutes)
            # create and start the daemon thread
            print('Starting background task...')
            daemon = Thread(target=timeCheck, args=(futureTime, interval_sec,), daemon=True, name='Background')
            daemon.start()
            print('Main thread is carrying on...')
            time.sleep(interval_sec)
            print('Main thread done running.')
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Enter a number.")
  
def timeConfirmation(hours, minutes):
    print(f"{hours}:{minutes} (hours:minutes)")
    currentDateTime = time.ctime()
    print(f"\n Current Date and Time: {currentDateTime}")
    timeInSeconds = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60)
    futureTime = time.time() + timeInSeconds
    print(f"\n Timer Ends at: {time.ctime(futureTime)}")
    return futureTime

def timeCheck(futureTime, interval_sec):
    while True:
        time.sleep(interval_sec)
        currentTime = time.time()
        if time.ctime(currentTime) == time.ctime(futureTime):
            alarmNotification()
        print(f"Checking time. {time.ctime(currentTime)}")

def alarmNotification():
   
    os.system("""
        osascript -e 'display notification "{}" with title "{}" sound name "{}"'
        """.format(f"Current time is: {time.ctime()}", "Its Break Time Boi", "Boop"))      


userTimeSet()
```

I have already integrated Django and started the project (created a urls.py and modified views to get HTTPResponse) I need to know how I can implement my python code and how I can connect it to the HTML from Django.

If this question was confusing please ask questions I am a beginner and I might not have said things correctly.

Comment: This is a CLI app. What do you mean by "connecting it to the HTML from Django"?

Comment: I don't want it t be a CLI app I want to take the user entry from an html form and then pass it to my backend to have it run in the background until the timer reaches its end, is there a way to do that using Django?

Answer (score 0):

This is a CLI app, to make it a django app, you have to set up some views in html, and link the django views to your python application, this sounds quite complicated, but don't worry, it is as simple as writing normal HTML files ^^ Django provides a lot of tools to help you build forms and accept an input from your website users, and then process with the data you got from the inputs.

These are 2 links to help you start with;

- This one is the official [**Django - Working with Forms**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/).
- And this a step by step tutorial from OpenClassRooms: [**Capture User Input With Django Forms**](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/6967196-create-a-web-application-with-django/7349237-capture-user-input-with-django-forms)

Good luck with your python journey !

Answer (score 0):

To link your Django backend to the frontend HTML, you should use [Django HTML templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/language/) that allows you to use Django syntax in HTML to apply backend logic and value into frontend

Follow very well the docs to understand about [django views here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/views/)

If you want to understand about how to render the HTML from Django and use the Django templating engine, then check out those two places